# Big O of list resize

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o

This question applies to all languages but let me stick to C#

```
var names = new List<string> {"Jerry", "Cosmo", "Elaine", "George"};
```

This is my compile time list. If I decide to insert record into it, then .Net underneath doubles the length from 4 to 8.

```
names.Insert("Newman");
```

Does Big-O of this insert method above become O(N)? Where N as length of the list? If yes, do most interviewers really care?

**EDIT**

Lets say we are inserting 1000 records.. Length will double at 4, 8, 16, 32.... So insert complexity will be Log(N) correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complexity for that *particular* insert operation (where the list doubles in size) is O(N). *But* the **amortized** complexity is still O(1), because the list did not double in size for the `N / 2` elements before, so the *average* number of operations per insertion is still constant. The interviewers probably expect you to be aware of this difference.

Comment: hmm.. Thats for triggering my thinking.. So lets say we are inserting 1000 records.. Length will double at 4, 8, 16, 32.... So complexity will be Log(N) right?

Comment: @om471987 no, the number of *size-doubling* operations is O(log(N)), but each size doubling operation is O(N). so you have a geometric series N + N / 2 + N / 4 + N / 8 ... for log(N) terms, which still converges O(N)